chrome extention code only work when inspect
I am writing a chrome extension that read excel file and store user id and grade into chrome.storage.local. The extension uses popup.js and popup.html to do that.
when debug (use extention inspect), it works well. but when I do not use inspect tool, it won't work.
I have installed the extension in debug mode, and running it using extension inspect tool, everything seems work well. The code read the excel file, and choose the 2 columns that I need to store. If I do not use extension inspect tool, it won't work. Each time, I uninstall the extention to remove the chrome.storage.local content. I also let all other chrome extension won't work.
document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            try {
                const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

                // Get the second sheet
                const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[1];
                const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

                // Convert sheet to JSON
                const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });

                // Extract the headers and find indices for "人员编号" and "最终成绩"
                const headers = jsonData[0];
                const idIndex = headers.indexOf("人员编号");
                const scoreIndex = headers.indexOf("最终成绩");

                if (idIndex === -1 || scoreIndex === -1) {
                    throw new Error('Required headers not found');
                }

                const extractedData = jsonData.slice(1).map(row => {
                    return {
                        "人员编号": row[idIndex],
                        "最终成绩": row[scoreIndex]
                    };
                });

                console.log('Extracted data:', extractedData);

                // Store in chrome.storage.local
                chrome.storage.local.set({ extractedData }, function() {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                        console.error('Error saving data:', chrome.runtime.lastError);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Data saved successfully.');
                    }
                });

                // Optionally display the extracted data
                document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = JSON.stringify(extractedData, null, 2);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error processing file:', error);
                document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = 'Error processing file.';
            }
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});



// Load stored file name and content when the popup opens

chrome.storage.local.get(['extractedData'], function(result) {
    // Check for runtime errors
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error('Error retrieving data:', chrome.runtime.lastError);
        document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = 'Error retrieving file data.';
        return;
    }

    // Display retrieved data or a message if not found
    const fileContentElement = document.getElementById('fileContent');
    if (result.extractedData) {
        fileContentElement.textContent = `File: \n${JSON.stringify(result.extractedData, null, 2)}`;
    } else {
        fileContentElement.textContent = 'No file data found.';
    }
});


and popuo.html is very simple:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Load Local File</title>
    <script src="lib/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".xlsx, .xls" />
    <pre id="fileContent"></pre>
    <button id="insertButton1">Insert 1</button>
    <button id="insertButton2">Insert 2</button>
   
    <button id="resetColor">Reset</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>


https://crbug.com/40700105
